# jQuery - simple way to bind json content to element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

Ever since Knockout and Angularjs presented a simpler way to otput content from JSON files, I find myself resorting to using them in instances when I would much rather use jQuery for simple tasks.

What would be the simplest way to display some content on the page using jQuery that would be equivalent to `{{ model }}` in angularjs?

For example, if  I have a json file:

```
{
    "something-1": "A",
    "something-2": "B",
    "something-3": "C"
}
```

this allows me to output content from data.json in a template by simply using curly brackets...

```
$http.get("data.json").success(function(data) 
{
    $scope.content = data;
});
```

Then in HTML:

```
{{ content['something-1'] }} <br/>
{{ content['something-2'] }} <br/>
{{ content['something-3'] }}
```

In jQuery using a simple ajax call to a json file allows me to read the file contents but I am unaware of any way that would allow me a simple and practical data output such as angularjs does.

Can someone suggest a practical way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to use something like mustache.js (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), jquery has some plugin but nothing inside the core library.

Comment: This looks interesting. Thanks! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

[underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template) also provides this option.

```
var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
compiled({name: 'moe'});
=> "hello: moe"
```